# Submit form to Servlet AEM

Tags: java, aem, sling

**The Servlet code looks like below**

```
@SlingServlet(
        methods = {"POST"},
        resourceTypes = {"cq:Page"},
        extensions = {"html"})
public class AssetDownloadServlet extends SlingAllMethodsServlet {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AssetDownloadServlet.class);


    @Override
    protected void doPost(SlingHttpServletRequest request, SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        log.info("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%$$$$$$$$$$$%%%%%%%**************:   "+ "doPost");
        processRequest(request,response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(SlingHttpServletRequest request, SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        log.info("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%$$$$$$$$$$$%%%%%%%**************:   "+ "doGet");
        processRequest(request,response);
    }

    private void processRequest(SlingHttpServletRequest request, SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{
        log.info("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%$$$$$$$$$$$%%%%%%%*******************");
        log.info(request.getParameter("format"));
        log.info("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%$$$$$$$$$$$%%%%%%%*******************");
    }
}
```

**The form in html page looks like below**

```
<form method="POST">
  <fieldset>
    <p>Format needed?</p>
    <ul style="list-style-type:none" data-sly-list.rendition="${renditions}">
      <!--${rendition.path}-->
      <li>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="format" value="${rendition.name}" />
          <span>${rendition.displayName}</span>
        </label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <button type="submit">Start Download</button>
    <a>Cancel Download</a>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

**CQ Details on the Page**

```
<!--cq{"decorated":false,"type":"myProject/components/page/generic","path":"/content/myProject/en/assetdetail/jcr:content","selectors":"IRNHUF7D","servlet":"Script /libs/foundation/components/page/page.jsp","totalTime":28,"selfTime":8}-->
```

**Summary:**

I have a cq:page resource, with a form and servlet linked to it. But on submitting the form the servlet is not betting initiated. I see that properties are set properly in http://localhost:4502/system/console/ .

Please suggest..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cq:Page` is not a resourceType, its a nodeType. You need to fix the resourceType in the servlet to your `sling:resourceType` in `jcr:content` node of the page. Another thing to note is that your servlet with a resourceType set will not be invoked if your path points to cq:Page node, it needs to point to `jcr:content` node to be picked up by the servlet.

```
@SlingServlet(
        methods = {"POST"},
        resourceTypes = {"path/to/resource/type"},
        extensions = {"html"})
public class AssetDownloadServlet extends SlingAllMethodsServlet {
```

And your form definition should be like -

```
<form method="POST" action="${currentPage.path}/_jcr_content.html">
```

Note that `jcr:content` is written as `_jcr_content`

Comment: I tried out your suggestion. But issue still exists. I don't see any changes in logs as well.

Comment: My bad, i have amended the URL in my reply above, its <path>/_jcr_content.html not <path>._jcr_content.html

Comment: I tried even this, it didn't go well. I have add CQ information which i receive on the page in the above snippet.

Comment: What you have posted is the GET request served by `page.jsp`, could you place your logs from `http://localhost:4502/system/console/requests` in the question. On this console you will see your POST request after form submit, something like `POST _jcr_content.html`, click on it to get the request information. Copy paste that information to the question. Also did you check if your servlet is active? You could check that on `/system/console/components` search for class name and verify the status, it should be active

Comment: Two things: 1/ remove the trailing ".html" (and the extensions property of the SlingServlet annotation); 2/ Check if your servlet is active at http://localhost:4502/system/console/components. It's good practice to name your component by adding a value for the "name" property of the SlingServlet annotation (the FQ class name is a good practice).

Comment: Thanks guys for the inputs. The servlet was active. There was a JS which was creating trouble on form submit. 
Logs at http://localhost:45‌​02/system/console/req‌​uests , were very helpful.